# Xcuitest: tapping at a specific location using x y coordinates not triggering the controls at that location

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcuitest, xcuiautomation

A simple iPad application has only a `UIbutton`. If tapping it will change its background color. If tapping happens outside the button the background of the application changes.

Now I’m trying to tap on the button using the x and y coordinates of the button. I do not see any change in the background of the button or even the background color of the application.

Code for Reference:

```swift
func testElementsOfMainScreen() {
     
    let app = XCUIApplication()
     
    let buttonFrame = app.buttons["AutoTap"].frame

    let buttonX = buttonFrame.origin.x
    let buttonY = buttonFrame.origin.y
     
    let tapCoordinates = CGVector(dx: buttonX+5, dy: buttonY+5)
    let coordinate = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: tapCoordinates)
     
    coordinate.tap()
}
```

Comment: Can I ask when you're tapping coordinates instead of the button itself?